# Use awk to prepend the line with a specific field of the line

Tags: text-processing, awk

Using `awk`, I'm trying to print the fourth field of an input line (`$4`) also at the begining of the line.

I have tried the following code, but it prints the string *above* the line:

```
awk -F"[--]" '{print $4 ;print$0}' file
```

The string is random so I can't use the string name.

The input like looks as follows:

```
/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

With the code above I get:

```
320
/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

I need the output to look like:

```
320/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate print statements will print separate records (lines) by default. Use a single `print`, concatenating `$4` and `$0`:

```
% awk -F- '{print $4 $0}' input
320/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

Answer (score 1):

If some of your dashes at the start of the lines disappear, it will be difficult to pick out the string to prepend to each line by its field number as it may not always be field 4, as in

```
$ cat file
/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
/example.origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
/example.origin.live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

Instead, the following picks out the second `-`-delimited word after the `:` on each line:

```
$ sed 's/^\([^:]*:[^-]*-\([^-]*\)\)/\2\1/' file
320/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin.live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

Or, arguably more readable with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F ':' '{ split($2,a,"-"); print a[2] $0 }' file
320/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin.live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```

That assumes that the line is basically two `:`-delimited fields, then splits the second of these up on `-` and uses the second of the resulting fields for the output.

If the end bit of each line has static formatting, then you could obviously count fields from the end instead of from the start and use `awk` like so:

```
$ awk -F '-' '{ print $(NF - 5) $0 }' file
320/example-origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin-live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
320/example.origin.live/ngrp:tennis-320-fd1d9b92-69e2-446c-a3e6-45b33a55efc9
```